# In SuiteScript how to prevent search from prepending itemid with parent's itemid and a colon

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have an item record which has the parent field set.
When I look on the web page of this item record, I see its itemid

> ITEM NAME/NUMBER 
> CHILD-ITEMID

Sorry, had to censor the actual itemid.

[image: item's page screenshot]

Also when I use the NetSuite field explorer plugin I also see the same value, which is what I expect, it's correct.

But when I try to get the itemid via the SuiteScript `N/search` module

```
require([
  'N/search',
], function (search) {
  const searchIns = search.create({
    type: 'serializedassemblyitem',
    filters: ['internalid', 'is', '123123',],
    columns: ['itemid',],
  });
  const results = searchIns.run();
  results.each((r) => {
    console.log('here');
    console.log(r.getValue('itemid'));
  });
});
```

I get:

> PARENT-ITEMID : CHILD-ITEMID

If I use the `N/record` module, it's correct, but I need to use the `N/search`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a formula to remove the prefix

```js
...columns:[
'itemid',
search.createColumn({name:'formulatext', formula:"REGEXP_REPLACE({itemid}, '.*:\\s?', '')"})

]
```

or if there is a possibility of the parent name having a colon : then something like the below works. The wrapping `REGEXP_REPLACE` cleans the colon and space prefixing the basic name.

```js
search.createColumn({name:'formulatext', formula:"REGEXP_REPLACE(REPLACE({itemid}, nvl({parent}, ''), ''), '.*:\\s?', '')"})
```

Comment: sorry, not very reliable. The parent item's itemid can contain who knows what. Like 'PPO : Foo : Bar' etc. Thank you for help though

Comment: Fixed. that was from some older script in my archive. For context the original offering was `search.createColumn({name:'formulatext', formula:"REGEXP_REPLACE({itemid}, '.*:\\s?(.*)', '\\1')"})` which does indeed fail on  items more than a single level deep or that have colons in their name (which should be disallowed)